# eloqua Oauth 2.0 submit forms

Tags: java, forms, oauth-2.0, eloqua

In my application i'm using eloqua OAuth 2.0 method for authentication. I was able to establish connection and successfully got access_token and refresh_token in the format below:

{
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA"
}

I'm trying to understand the next steps on how to make Eloqua rest api call using the access token I received?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the oauth docs for Eloqua: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/GettingStarted/Authentication/authenticate-using-oauth.htm

Add the following header to your request:

```
Authorization: Bearer 2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA
```